# Where do I start for writing my own calculator program

Tags: javascript, c++, desktop-application

I have been learning programing, mainly JavaScript and C++, but all the programs I have been writing are simple and in note pad like applications.

What would I need to make a simple calculator that takes user input and dose calculations with it.

What would I use to get the GUI on the screen, how would I compile it, and what IDE should I use.

Comment: for GUI applications, you can try QT

Comment: Try the wizards in MVS

Comment: wxWidgets, QT, there are many GUI libraries out there. You are going to want a text editor that offers syntax highlighting and error checking at a minimum. I recommend installing an IDE (integrated development environment), it will make your life easier starting out.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an appropriate question to ask here, as it is too open ended. But in situations like yours, what I do is I take what I know, and see what I can build, maybe look up on google for advanced tutorials and the like.  Try making something that reads a file, and writes to another file but in reverse, try writing a program that listens on a port on one computer, and writing a program that sends to that computer from another machine.

Comment: The same you began learning to read; from the beginning.  You didn't start with Shakespeare, right?  Start by learning the basics, i.e., understand your language, how a program executes, its semantics, etc.

Comment: try to ask one question at a time, ie whats a good javascript ID, how do i lay out the UI elements in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how complicated you're going, it'd be easier to recommend if you had a specific project in mind. You could make a simple 'GUI' that just opens in a CMD/Terminal window with C++ and easily allow input (`cin`), changing what's displayed as you desire. You could easily do your example this way, without the need of anything overly complex.

In terms of using Notepad you probably want something with at least some sort of formatting to make it a bit easier on yourself (such as Notepad++) although you could just open Notepad and start coding. There are IDEs such as Eclipse with the CDT plugin which are good for starting C++, or Visual Studio. I'm not big on Javascript myself, but I've heard Komodo is good for web coding.

In terms of complex GUIs, as has been said in the comments there are many and it basically comes down to your preference as to which you use.

Comment: This pretty much answered my question, sorry for the previous question that was way to general.
I was just confused about how to get certain things like(GUI,IDE,compiling-(I'm assuming the IDE handles this))
Also thanks to CBredlow,

Comment: i would mark this as an accepted answer if it did satisfy your question with the green check box next to it.

Comment: @JackBarn Yeah IDE's handle compiling, although Eclipse can be a bit of a pain to set up for C++, for that I recommend you check this: http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-install-mingw-msys-and-eclipse-on-windows/ - GUI is written in your code obviously, but configuring the libraries you may need is a lot easier with something like Eclipse to help you along.

Answer (score 1):

If it is basic to advance experience you seek then try Windows Forms application. Make a calculator or something. Sky (and memory) is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to write an application in my eyes is to need that application in the first place. So try to think of some tool, you or someone else might need and then re-think your process.

With a clear aim you can start off and think of everything you need and - even more important - we can help you in this community, because you can then ask more specific questions regarding the actual development and all the problems that occur alongside it.

Answer (score 0):

Develop deep understanding of c++ concepts. Study more and good books including it's standard. Start with normal applications & go towards advanced programming. for GUI, try `QT` - it's good of go for MFC Application. Write Code yourself and work on different projects, alogirithms. For book suggestion, i suggest you getting [Scott Mayers Effective c++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)

For Compiler, i suggest using Visual Studio on widnows - it's awesome IDE.